# Matching two identical groups of characters in pandas with some number of characters in between

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'm trying to extract two numbers of interest from a string of docket text in a pandas dataframe. Here's an example with a couple of the idiosyncrasies that exist in the data

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(["Fee: $ 15,732, and Expenses: $1,520.62."])
```

I used regexr to test some ideas and the closest I've been able to come up with is something along the lines of

```
df[0].str.extract("(\${0,2}\s*(\d+[,\.]*){1,5})")
```

Which returns:

```
           0    1
0   $15,732,,   732,,
```

The problems I'm running into are making characters optional while capturing the groups (i.e. I don't know how to get rid of the inner parenthesis because if I make it brackets then I get an error). And then ideally I'd be able to match the other set of numbers too.

I used regexr and while I can make regular expressions that match what I want, I'm struggling with the grouping part so that I can capture both while not needing to use a cumbersome function like `apply` with `re`.

There are sometimes numbers that show up again later in the report that include dates, other numbers, etc... So I'm trying to find a pretty controlled sequence (Can't get too liberal with the .*'s haha)

---

---

The string I ended up writing after the hint provided in the comments is:

`\$((?:\d+(?:[,\.])*)+).*?\$((?:\d+(?:[,\.])*)+)`. The non-matching groups is what I hadn't understood before. I thought non-matching groups meant that it would somehow remove the parts that matched from the group but really what it means is that it's a group of characters that don't count as a group (not that they'll be removed from a group).

I appreciate the feedback I got this post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
df[0].str.extract(r"(\$\s*\d+(?:[,.]\d+)*)")    # To get the first value
df[0].str.extractall(r"(\$\s*\d+(?:[,.]\d+)*)") # To get all values
df[0].str.findall(r"\$\s*\d+(?:[,.]\d+)*")      # To get all values
```

The `str.extract` pattern is wrapped with a capturing group so that the method could return any value, it requires at least one capturing group in the regex pattern.

The regex matches

- `\$` - a `$` char
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `(?:[,.]\d+)*` - a non-capturing group matching zero or more repetitions of a comma/dot and then one or more digits.

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/4znxZV/1).

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if the text stays the same across all of the values but you can use the following regex:

```
r'Fee: \$\s?([\d,.]+), and Expenses:\s*\$\s?([\d,.]+)\.'
```

[returning two matching groups:](https://pythex.org/?regex=Fee%3A%20%5C%24%5Cs%3F(%5B%5Cd%2C.%5D%2B)%2C%20and%20Expenses%3A%5Cs*%5C%24%5Cs%3F(%5B%5Cd%2C.%5D%2B)%5C.&test_string=Fee%3A%20%24%2015%2C732%2C%20and%20Expenses%3A%20%241%2C520.62.&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

```
15,732
1,520.62
```

You can also abstract the text:

```
r'\w+:\s*\$\s?([\d,.]+),(\s*\w+)+:\s*\$\s?([\d,.]+)\.'
```

[with the same result](https://pythex.org/?regex=%5Cw%2B%3A%5Cs*%5C%24%5Cs%3F(%5B%5Cd%2C.%5D%2B)%2C(%5Cs*%5Cw%2B)%2B%3A%5Cs*%5C%24%5Cs%3F(%5B%5Cd%2C.%5D%2B)%5C.&test_string=Fee%3A%20%24%2015%2C732%2C%20and%20Expenses%3A%20%241%2C520.62.&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I went with @Wiktors because my case needs to be a bit more general but this is a good answer!